# Error after renaming main Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

after renaming my main class to "Main" and my main xml to "main" i could start my application.
i keep getting this logcat:

```
08-28 21:46:27.563: D/AndroidRuntime(264): Shutting down VM
08-28 21:46:27.563: W/dalvikvm(264): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
08-28 21:46:27.563: E/AndroidRuntime(264): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{noc.support/noc.support.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at noc.support.Main.onCreate(Main.java:116)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  ... 11 more
08-28 21:46:27.653: I/dalvikvm(264): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
08-28 21:46:27.663: I/dalvikvm(264): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-28 21:47:07.853: I/Process(264): Sending signal. PID: 264 SIG: 9
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="noc.support"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">

        <service android:name=".BootListnerService" android:label="Boot Service">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="noc.support.BootListnerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".BootListnerServiceReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="BootListnerServiceReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Register" android:label="Register"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".Settings" android:label="Settings"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".ServersStatus" android:label="Servers Status"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailLable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Email:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailField"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passwordLable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Password:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:inputType="textPassword" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/rememberEmailPasswordCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Remember my email &amp; password" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/loginAutomaticallyCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login automatically" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:paddingRight="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="40dp">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.05"
            android:text="Add" />




        <Button
            android:id="@+id/refreshButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.86"
            android:text="Refresh" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

what am i doing wrong?

does anyone have any ideas.

i googled it but i couldn't find the fix.

when i change "setContentView(R.layout.main);" to any other layout it works fin, but i need this class to start with main.xml

Comment: Could you post more lines of you logcat exception?Specially the _caused by_ line.  The exception is a NPE, and not a ResourceNotFound, Activity not found, and other problems that would be common in a not properly cleaned project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by creating a new project and copied all my files into that project but i didn't replace the main class or the layout instead i copied and pasted the inner code of the class of those two but kept the  class name. this way the class name is correct.

Comment: i don't know if there is a better solution, but it did the trick

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it is still trying to launch activity "ComponentInfo". If you have changed all of your files, but not your package name, then you are probably installing the new application on top of the old one, and the old launcher points to the old activity, which no longer exists.

**In Short:** Try deleting your old application and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `NullPointerException` on line 116 of Main.java (your activity). Should be pretty easy to find yourself, or post the code for Main.java here.

```
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 21:46:27.623: E/AndroidRuntime(264):  at noc.support.Main.onCreate(Main.java:116)
```